# How to create bootstrap html structure in php loop?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, loops

I'm using bootstrap and need to create structure like this

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!--content loop 1-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!--content loop 1-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!--content loop 2-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!--content loop 2-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!--content loop 3-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!--content loop 3-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!--content loop 4-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!--content loop 4-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to create it in a single foreach loop but on each loop I only create this structure.

```
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <!--content loop 1-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <!--content loop 1-->
    </div>
```

I can create the first `<div class="row"></div>` outside of the loop but how can I break out of the loop to create the second `<div class="row"></div>` and continue the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do some thing like this. You can modify according to your need.
I just mentioned logic

```
   <div class="row">
     <?php
         $i = 0;
         foreach(....../*your code*/){
           if($i == 4){
               $i = 0;
              ?>
                  </div><div class="row">
                <?php
            } 
                ?>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
               <!--content-->
            </div>
          <?php
            $i++;
         }
        ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: I thought this was working but it seems to miss or skip the 3rd position in the array - I have a demo here http://viper-7.com/EsGoc9. I want 2 divs in each row and two rows. I have just output the array elements and it misses the 3rd element

Comment: yes it seems i missed it. see the edit i made in answer. and check edit here http://viper-7.com/bRjxb3

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as following this logic:

```
for($i = 0;$i < 4;$i++) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    for($j = 0;$j < 4;$j++) {
        echo '<div class="col-sm-3"></div>';
    }
    echo '</div>;'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this way because i think is cleaner and easier to manage:

```
<?php
    $colsOffset = 4;
    $items = array('content1','content2','content3','etc...');
    $i = 0;
?>
<?php foreach ( $items as $item ) { ?>
    <?php echo ($i % $colsOffset == 0 || $i == 0) ? '<div class="row">' : '' ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <!--content loop-->
    </div>
    <?php echo (($i + 1) % $colsOffset == 0 || ($i + 1) == count($items)) ? '</div>' : '' ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
<?php } ?>
```